# Android - add subview with layout params at specific index (in code)

Tags: android, android-view, layoutparams

I may be missing something, but I can't find a way to add a subview to a view at a specified index with specific layout params.  There's `addView(View v, LayoutParams lp)` and there's `addView(View v, int index)` - but I can't find a way to specify both.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why, there's a method with both: `addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)`: [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29).

Comment: Hm, really. Why is my eclipse complaining?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example. I use it to show a progress indicator on any view.

```
final ViewGroup rootFrameLayout = (ViewGroup) activity.getWindow().peekDecorView();
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
progressView = li.inflate(R.layout.progressindicator, null);
rootFrameLayout.addView(progressView);
```

Here is a sample layout file (id is R.layout.progressindicator)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:lines="3"
    android:background="#88000000"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="@string/waitingForServer" />
```

Just in case you want to change the layout also dynamically then you can call the methods of the elements in the layout. Like this:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) progressView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView.setMaxLines(lines);
textView.setLines(lines);
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question. Where are you specifying the layout params?

Comment: @AleksG I added the layout file and explained how it is used.

Comment: I still don't understand how all of this answers the question.  I don't have any layout files - I create views on the fly in the code.  I need to add the view to a parent view - on the fly in the code - while specifying layout parameters.  Your answer doesn't attempt to do any of this.