# Android draw view on canvas from HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, view, draw, android-canvas, horizontalscrollview

I have in my layout sticky header within horizontallScrollView within scrollview. I make my header sticky by draw header view on canvas. My problem is that i don't know how to scroll view(blue), to draw another part of its. This problem is ilustrated by image belowe.

[image: draw view on canvas from horizontalScrollView]

Now i know only how to draw blue part of header view. But i want draw yellow part of view. Could You give me same advice?

Answer (score 0):

Start with the parent and use addsubview to add the views in particular places.

[Android - add subview with layout params at specific index (in code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929439/android-add-subview-with-layout-params-at-specific-index-in-code)

Comment: It is good solution if yellow part is static, but yellow view is scrolling while horizontalScrollView is scrolling.